# Better way to detect the number of consecutive records for a lot of different unique user IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

So I'm currently waiting for my query to run (which takes about 5 minutes)

I have developed a query that will look at a student's attendance record, identify a run of Attendance Codes and group them based on date and class time.

This query works great if i'm trying to find the highest number of absences for a particular student but becomes trickier when I try to create a table which shows the highest run of absences for all active students.

To achieve this I am using a cursor to assign the StudentNo (unique id) to a parameter and then run my original query, and place the results into a Temporary table called @results.

Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @StudentId INT
DECLARE @getStudentId CURSOR
DECLARE @Results TABLE(StudentNo INT,AttendanceCode VarChar(2),StartDate       DateTime,EndDate DateTime,"# of Classes" INT)
SET @getStudentId = CURSOR FOR
SELECT StudentNo
FROM [dbo].[Students]
OPEN @getStudentId
FETCH NEXT
FROM @getStudentId INTO @StudentId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

WITH AttendanceCodeMaster AS
(SELECT 
    [dbo].[Students].StudentNo,
    CAST(CONVERT(date,[dbo].[CourseOfferingSchedule].ClassDate,101) as DATETIME) + CAST(CONVERT(time,dbo.CourseOfferingSchedule.ClassStartTime,101) AS DATETIME) as ClassDate,
    [dbo].[CourseOfferingAttendanceScheduled].AttendanceCode

FROM [dbo].[CourseOfferingAttendanceScheduled]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Students] on [dbo].[CourseOfferingAttendanceScheduled].StudentNo = [dbo].[Students].StudentNo 
    INNER JOIN dbo.[CourseOfferingSchedule] on [dbo].[CourseOfferingAttendanceScheduled].ScheduleID =  [dbo].[CourseOfferingSchedule].ScheduleID
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[StudentStatus] on  [dbo].[Students].StudentStatusID =  [dbo].[StudentStatus].StudentStatusID

where 

[dbo].[Students].StudentNo = @StudentId and StudentStatus = 'Active' and Complete = 'Y' 

),

RunGroup AS
(SELECT StudentNo,ClassDate, AttendanceCode, (SELECT COUNT(*) From AttendanceCodeMaster as G WHERE G.AttendanceCode <> GR.AttendanceCode AND G.ClassDate <= GR.ClassDate) as RunGroup
FROM AttendanceCodeMaster as GR ),

AbsenceStreaks AS
(SELECT 
StudentNo,
AttendanceCode, 
MIN(ClassDate) as StartDate, 
MAX(ClassDate)as EndDate,
COUNT(*) as '# of Classes' 
FROM RunGroup
where AttendanceCode = 'A'
GROUP BY StudentNo,AttendanceCode, RunGroup),

LongestStreak AS
(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM AbsenceStreaks
Order BY '# of Classes' Desc)

INSERT INTO @Results SELECT * FROM LongestStreak

FETCH NEXT
FROM @getStudentId INTO @StudentId

END
CLOSE @getStudentId
DEALLOCATE @getStudentId

SELECT * from @Results
where "# of Classes" >= 30

order by StudentNo
```

Comment: What's your problem exactly?

Comment: Tip 1:  Use aliases and indenting to make your code easier to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need a cursor to solve this problem.  The following may be making some assumptions on field contents and names (because it is hard to follow your query logic), but it should give you the right approach.

The key is that a string of absences can be recognized by enumerating all class days for a student (in a class) and then enumerating all class days for a student by whether or not they attended.  The difference between these values is constant, for a sequence of absences or presences.

```
select studentNo, grp, AttendanceCode, count(*) as numInRow,
       min(ClassDate) as DateStart, max(ClassDate) as DateEnd
from (select acm.*
             (row_number() over (partition by StudentNo order by ClassDate) -
              row_number() over (partition by StudentNo, AttendanceCode order by ClassDate) 
             ) as grp
      from AttendanceCodeMaster acm
     ) acm
group by studentNo, grp, AttendanceCode;
```

(I'm not sure if there is a class code in there somewhere as well.)

This should give you the information you want to find sequences of absences or presences.

StudentNo,ClassDate, AttendanceCode, (SELECT COUNT(*) From AttendanceCodeMaster as G WHERE G.AttendanceCode <> GR.AttendanceCode AND G.ClassDate <= GR.ClassDate) as RunGroup
FROM AttendanceCodeMaster

Comment: Wow this was a lot faster than the way I was doing it before thank you!  Also I was on vacation last week otherwise I would have thanked you earlier!